# Checking if a polynomial expression is constant in SAGE

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, sagemath

I have a huge fractional-polynomial expression in SAGE that I have good reasons to believe is the constant function. Is there a command in SAGE like "== constant function" that I could use to check that hypothesis?

Comment: I am not too familiar with SAGE (or questions of this type), but if the numerator is a polynomial, then you could simply write a quick a program to evaluate the function  at a few more random points than the degree of the polynomial.  I suppose that this strategy depends on exactly how huge the fractional polynomial expression is and whether or not the degree is known.

Comment: @THW yes I thought of doing this, but the expression that I had was a sum of several fractions and it would take a while to collect by hand the numerators and denominators of every fraction. Unless, of course, there were another function of sage that would write a sum of fraction as one fraction only.

Comment: If you have a minimal example (how to generate it would suffice) then one could play around with the many simplification/expansion commands to see whether this one works.

Comment: hi @kcrisman! exactly! Do you have a list of all those simplification/expansion commands? I only know simplify() and expand(), and I couldn't figure out with only those two. Maybe there are also "right everything over the same denominator"(), "factor f = gh+r"() where r is the remainder, etc...

Answer (score 1):

The methods on symbolic expressions are at [the documentation for symbolic expressions](http://sagemath.org/doc/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/expression.html).

Maybe you will find the [`denominator` method](http://sagemath.org/doc/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/expression.html#sage.symbolic.expression.Expression.denominator) useful?

Comment: Hi! I looked in the documentation for something that could help. I found out that the function will at least put everything in the same denominator. So this solves part of the problem, because now I can use the method denominator. However, factor is still disappointing inasmuch as it doesn't factor a low degree polynomial even when explicit formulas are available. I described the issue here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750094/in-sage-what-function-factors-a-polynomial-whose-coefficients-are-parameters. Do you know a solution?